# Specify maven dependencies for packages

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible in maven project to sepecify in the dependecies, which one is    applied for which java package ? If it's possible how ?

Example: I have two package:

```
1) org.test.compute
2) org.test.stock
```

And dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.35</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

my goal is:

aws-java-sdk applied to org.test.compute

and org.cloudfoundry to org.test.stock

Comment: What do you mean **package**?

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Why not use both the dependencies in test scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. All packages of a Java application are included in the same runtime classpath, so all of the dependencies that are on the classpath are visible in all of the packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a multi-module project in maven.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's only because there is two classes with the same name in the two dependencies, I suggest to use full qualified names when you're using the classes like:

```
org.cloudfoundry.pathA.classA
com.amazonaws.pathB.classA
```

Also, if the dependencies are only used in the test classes, you want to use the test scope like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.35</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

By doing so, the dependecy will be only used while compiling and running the tests. It will not be included in the final WAR or EAR file.